# Getting Access Denied While Accessing the Named Pipe from Another System

Tags: permissions, firewall, named-pipes

I have a Named Pipe and It Works Fine While I access it using a Client which runs on My System.

I get GLE 5 (Access denied) while I run the client from another system.

The original post is at [stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3667144/getting-access-denied-while-accessing-the-named-pipe-from-another-system)

Answer (score 0):

Check the security policy settings on that machine for "Named Pipes that can be accessed remotely" and add yours. Some good info here: [Link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/blogs/spatdsg/fyi-changes-to-null-session-pipes-post-2k3-sp1)